# Post Data, received by Express server with multer middleware, is truncated

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, multer

I'm sending a 1.5MB string via a POST request to my Express server but when I look at the data received it's only 786 KB long.
The string I'm sending is a base64 image string. I've also tried to change the limits of multer to no avail.

**CLIENT:**

```
function upload(file) {
var form = new FormData(),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
form.append('filename', "imageName.jpg");
form.append('imageData', file);
xhr.open('post', 'http://server/imgdata', true);
xhr.send(form);
}
```

**SERVER:**

```
app.use(multer({
dest: './uploads/',
// WILL RENAME THE RECEIVED FILE
rename: function(fieldname, filename) {
    return filename + Date.now();
},
// UPLOAD HAS STARTED
onFileUploadStart: function(file) {
    console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
},
// FILE HAS BEEN RECEIVED AND SAVED
onFileUploadComplete: function(file) {
    console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
    done = true;
},
onFieldsLimit: function() {
    console.log('Crossed fields limit!')
}
 }));
app.post('/imgdata', function(req, res) {

// THIS IS RETURNS ONLY A PART OF THE DATA
res.json(req.body.image2);

var data = req.body.image2.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');

// THE IMAGE IS SAVED BUT ONLY THE 786KB OF IT EVERY TIME REGARDLESS     
// OF THE SIZE OF DATA SEND 
fs.writeFile('image.jpg', buf, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
})
```

Comment: Why not just send the file, `formData` supports image files directly

Comment: @adeneo this is just a proof of concept what the app will be doing is sending data from the canvas object

Comment: multer uses busboy internally, and looking at the documentation for that, it seems the default size for a textfield is 1mb, and as you're sending this as base64 it's just text, and you're probably hitting the max fieldSize limit

Comment: Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/2d72x9xn/

Comment: @adeneo I've tried your code but the saved image is again 786 KB. Is there maybe something else preventing the data of going through? The headers are showing the full size of the request but the image data always get cut in half...

Comment: I have no idea, try figuring out if `req.body.image2` has all the data, and where the data is being lost etc.

Comment: @adeneo thanks for the help. The req.body.image2 is cropped too...

Comment: Then try using the `body-parser` middleware instead of `multer`

Comment: Multer is what express recommends based on my understanding...

Comment: For multipart forms, yes, for regular www/encoded use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

Comment: @Manolis @adeneo `fieldSize` and similar limits are all in bytes, so it would need to be `5 * 1024 * 1024` and not just `5`, to be 5MB.

Comment: @Manolis @adeneo Also, the limits option name is `limits` and not `limit`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the limits of the multer middleware didn't fix the issue,

```
limits: {
    fieldNameSize : 100000, 
    fieldSize : 5242880 
},
```

but as per @adeneo's suggestion I gave bodyParser an other go and after changing the limit of urlencoded like so

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true,
limit: 100000000 
}));
```

I received all the data on the server and successfully saved the image.